# Swift: How to properly refactor UIButton

Tags: swift

Can someone give me an idea why this doesnt work. When selecting a button, my project crashes and say:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[ViewLifeCycle.ViewController handleTap]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1016eb7a0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

I remember doing something similar and it worked but i forgot.

```
let firstButton = createCustomButton(text: "First", color: UIColor.systemBlue, action: #selector(handleTap))
let secondButton = createCustomButton(text: "Second", color: UIColor.systemGreen, action: #selector(handleTap))
let thirdButton = createCustomButton(text: "Third", color: UIColor.systemPurple, action: #selector(handleTap))

static func createCustomButton(text: String, color: UIColor, action: Selector) -> UIButton {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.titleLabel?.text = text
    button.backgroundColor = color
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    button.titleLabel?.textColor = .red
    
    button.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
    
}

 @objc fileprivate func handleTap() {
    print("Handling tap")
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to "Refactor" your button. You need to fix a bug in the way you assigned the target/action to it.

Comment: A better title would be "Why does my app crash when the user taps a button?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's inside your static method.

Two way to solve:

1. Remove the static declaration
2. Pass the viewcontroller instance and use it as self while adding target to the button.

Comment: I  have it. just didnt think that was necessary. I edited it with it included.

Comment: Ratul told you what to do. (Voted.) In a static method, `self` is the class, not an instance of the class. Thus you are telling the button to try to invoke the IBAction on the class, which is not what you want. (If Ratul's answer solved our problem you should accept it.)